# "Vient prendre" -- Venir + verb. instead of "Venir de + verb"?

Tags: grammaire

I know that Venir de + verb means "to just have done [verb]". As in "Je viens de chanter" (I just did singing).

But in an article in a magazine I'm reading, I see:

> Le serveur vient prendre notre commande:

I cannot figure out what "vient prendre" means.

The WordReference [webpage](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/vient%20prendre) for venir does mention "venir de + [verb]" and "venir à + [verb]", but there is no entry for "venir [verb]", nor any "venir prendre".

Question:

1. What does this sentence mean? What does it mean to have "Venir + [verb]" (instead of "Venir de + [verb]"?)

---

Edit: this is the information I think is important from the accepted answer. (Some of this information is in the comments).

1. Venir + [infinitive verb] means "to come in order to [infinitive verb]". So, "Je viens chanter" means "I come to sing". "Il vient prendre notre commande" means "He comes to take our order".
2. The page for "venir" in the WordReference dictionary does not mention this! But typing "Venir definition" into google does tell us that Venir is a semi-auxiliary verb, and does tell us what "Venir + [infinitive verb]" means.
3. It seems that WordReference *never* tells us if a verb is semi-auxiliary or not (and what it means when it is used as a semi-auxiliary verb). (For example, WR's page for "aimer" does not tell us that "aimer" can be a semi-auxiliary verb). However, [this page](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/semi-auxiliary-verbs/) gives a list of many verbs that can be used as a semi-auxiliary verbs, and what they mean when they are used as a semi-auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence means "The waiter comes to take our order". Here the literal translation is the good one, the waiter comes and takes the order.

Wordreference gives this definition:

> venir chercher [qch] (aller récupérer [qch]) => come and pick [sth] up, come and fetch [sth]

Venir + [verb] means "To come in order to [verb]"

Comment: I did not know that a verb could follow a conjugated "venir", the way it can for (say) "aimer" (J'aime chanter). Is there any way that I could have found this out from the wordreference webpage for "venir"?

Comment: I edited the answer with what Wordreference says

Comment: But "venir chercher" is not "venir prendre"? Seeing "venir chercher" (if I even could find it in that very very long section!) wouldn't necessarily mean that, in general, "venir + [verb]" means "to come in order to [verb]"?

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Comment: But what I want to know is how can I find out that "Venir + [verb]" means "To come in order to [verb]" by myself (e.g., using a reference like a dictionary), instead of having to ask someone (e.g. using french.stackexchange) ?

Comment: When you type "venir definition" on google you get this definition : "(semi-auxiliaire ; + infinitif)
Se déplacer (pour faire).
J'irai la voir et ensuite je viendrai vous chercher."

Comment: oh! That is exactly what I had wanted. But now I wonder: are dictionaries note meant to give this information, then? Or was it just WordReference that is lacking, here?

Comment: I don't really know, I was surprised that Wordreference didn't have this exact definition though, I guess it is a lack.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I guess I have said this before but I will say it again. I have a dyslexia of two. **When there is a choice of two things, I often reverse them when I am not careful**. That's what I did here. Venir de: to have just done x Venir + verb: come to do x. Yes, with to.